# Swift In App Purchase Non Consumable

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I am developing IAP functionality of non consumable (removing Ads).
I've created an helper for all the operation and everything works fine.

When a user buy/restore the purchase i set this:

```
let save = UserDefaults.standard
save.set(true, forKey: "Purchase")
save.synchronize()
```

This works fine as long as the user never delete the app.

I was wondering...
Is there a way to know if the user (after deleting and reinstalling the app) already had made a purchase? so to change the title of the button from "purchase" to "restore"?

Comment: If you look at virtually *any* iOS app with IAP, you'll find that they all have a "Restore Purchases" button - required by Apple BTW - even if you've *never* made a purchase. All that happens is your purchases are restored - meaning nothing happens *except* a check for purchases. Why would you *want* your app to behave differently than every iOS user has come to expect?

Comment: The right way is to implement the "Restore purchases" button, so if the user deletes the app, the user can always restore it using this option. There should be another way, like saving the purchases states in the keychain (will persist even if the app is reinstalled) or by using the cloud. Careful with those! BTW, in your code, there's no need to use .syncronize() https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a login system you will know easily , otherwise

no other way you should put buy and restore buttons for payment Or you store this key-value in 
device **key-chain** and read them in first setup ,but you should know from **ios 10.3** If you deleted the app the associated **key-chain** items will be deleted

**Note: Apple** states that all apps that have IAP should put a restore payment functionality so, If there is a workaround app will be rejected by **Apple**

Comment: i have stored it in the keychain... and i have implemented the restore possibility... i was just trying to see if there is a way to change the button label if it is the first purchase or the restore... my issue with the key chain is, as you said, if the user delete/reinstall the app than it will have no value stored...

Comment: NOway to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

For every app, Apple requires that you include a "Restore Purchases" button. This is exactly for the problem you are facing. It will recreate the `SKPaymentTransaction` for every previously purchased IAP with a "restored" state for the iCloud account that is currently signed in at the App Store, and put on the `SKPaymentQueue`. [Read more...](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would make sense to have a receipt validation in your code, when the user is interacting in your app. (Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html)

Just have a look at this small example:

**Init your product requests:**

```
if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        print("starting IAPS")
        let productIdentifiers = Set(["YOUR_IAPP_IDENTIFIER#1", "YOUR_IAPP_IDENTIFIER#1"])
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()

} else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
}
```

**Set your products in your app and do the receipt validation**

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        if product.productIdentifier == "YOUR_IAPP_IDENTIFIER#1" {
            self.productYear = product
        } else if product.productIdentifier == "YOUR_IAPP_IDENTIFIER#2" {
            self.productMonth = product
        }

        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        self.receiptValidation()
 }
```

**Validation example**

```
  func receiptValidation() {
            self.logger.log.debug("In receipt validation")
            if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
                FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

                do {
                    let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)

                    let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                    let dict = ["receipt-data" : receiptString, "password" : "YOUR_PASSWORD"] as [String : Any]
                    // Getting the receipt data from the JSON file and other logic
                    // ...
                    // ...
          }
       }
    }
```

Please let me know, if you need more clarification on this. Furthermore you can simply restore it with the PaymentQueue (Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... i have done everything up to the product request. But i'm kind of new to swift (just few months) and never seen the validation... can you please explain a bit deeper how can i use it? does it return from the store data about the purchase?

Comment: I have implemented the restore part... i was just trying to display different button label depending if is the first purchase or he already purchased... using the userDefaults works until the user delete/reinstall the app... then obviously that value is not set anymore...